# Not able to find out of range value for a table column of Date type

Tags: sql-server

Executing the query `DBCC CHECKDB WITH NO_INFOMSGS` failed with the following error:

> *Page (1:2772455), slot 8 in object ID 689489585, index ID 1,
>   partition ID 72057594305052672, alloc unit ID 72057594619953152 (type
>   "In-row data"). Column "Date" value is out of range for data type
>   "datetime".*

Update column to a legal value.

I got above message while running `DBCC checkDB` command for a specific table of a database 
and when I tried to fetch the date column of that table by running below query:-

```
select [date] 
from  [TableName] 
where [Year] = 2011 
  and Month = 1 
  and [Date] < '1753-01-01'
  and Date > '9999-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Between` keyword like this:-

```
  select [date] from  [TableName] where [Year]=2011 and Month=1 and [Date] between ('1753-01-01','9999-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `WHERE clause` does not make sense

1. You are looking for Date which is **earlier than '1753-01-01'** *and*
   **later than '9999-12-31'** which does not exist.
2. `[Year] = 2011` means you need only 2011 records and no need to filter
   by a date range at all. For some reason if you need it should be as `[date] BETWEEN '17530101' AND '99991231`
3. It is recommended to use `ISO date format` which is `yyyymmdd` (ie;
   `'17530101'`). ***This could be the reason for Date out of range error.***

   I think this will do the job;

   ```
     SELECT [date] FROM  [TableName] WHERE [Year] = 2011 AND Month = 1 
     --AND [date] BETWEEN '17530101' AND '99991231' 
     --This filter does not make sense as you have already filtered by 2011.
   ```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find out the exact record where this Out of range value exist in the table. Please suggest me how I can find that value so I could fix that record. As per you suggestion, I again used ISO date format to find that record using below query

Comment: Query:-
select [date] from  Table1 where convert(varchar,Date,112) Not BETWEEN '17530101' AND '99991231'

Comment: yes, I am able to run above query but it is not providing any record which is having some date range issue.

Comment: Hi Kaf thanks for your post. I found one solution for finding the exact record which was having date range issue. I use Page Trace command:-   **DBCC TRACEON (3604 )**  
**DBCC PAGE ( ZoomReport,1,2772455,3)**. Here 2772455 is the page number where problem occurs this we can find by running DBCC command on DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have the page (1:2772455) that contains the corrupted value, run this to find out exactly what row is causing the problems:

```
DBCC TRACEON ( 3604 )
DBCC PAGE ( 'dbname' , 1 , 2772455 , printopt=3 )
DBCC TRACEOFF ( 3604 )
```

Search for "INVALID" and you will find Date = INVALID COLUMN VALUE.
Scroll up and get the primary key.
You can then UPDATE the row with a correct Date.